# How I know my site is indexed on AOL or not

Tags: search-engine-indexing, bing

How do I know is my site indexed on AOL or not?

How do I index it?

Answer (score 1):

AOL search is powered by bing. When you're on AOL.com and search for something, you can use the parameter `site:example.com`. It should show you if your site is indexed or not.

You can submit your site to be indexed by Bing by visiting this URL:
https://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/post/january-2016/bing-powers-aol-search), as of January 1, 2016, Bing powers AOL search.

Therefore, you can submit your site to Bing here: https://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url

You can check to see if your website is indexed on AOL Search / Bing by searching for:

```
site:example.com
```

This will search for all indexed results for your site.